# How do I replace an element?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the following HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>

</head>
<body>
  <table>
  <caption>table title and/or explanatory text</caption>
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>header</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
      <tr>
      <td id=\"test\" width=\"272\"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<a href=\"http://www.google.fi\" style=\"color:black\">Test link</a>
<a href=\"http://www.google.fi\"><img src=\"http://www.google.se/images/nav_logo95.png\" /></a>"
</body> 
</html>;
```

And  I want to find the first link with jsoup and replace it with a text

```
Element elem = page.select("a[href=" + link.getUrl() + "]:contains(" + link.getName() + ")").first();
```

I can only replace the inner HTML with `elem.html("foo")` or print the outerHtml with `elem.outerHtml()`

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the answer!

```
TextNode text = new TextNode("foo", "");
elem.replaceWith(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have found the element that you want to work with, you may apply the commands such as explained here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html

I could not get it right. I am trying this:

```
elemento.prepend("<a href='www.test.com'>");    
elemento.html("Roberto C. Santos.");                
elemento.append("</a>");
elemento.wrap("<a href='www.test.com'> </a>");
```

But I am getting this:

```
<td><a href="www.test.com"> <a style="" target="_self" title="" href="http://ivv.veveivv.vvzenes.com.br/mao/ara/ccacao" data-mce-href="resolveuid/5cc1c7c8c9efcacaaeedec22a9c69a54" class="internal-link">Roberto C. Santos.</a></a></td>
  </tr>
```

I still don´t know the exact way to exchange the contents of an URL element.

I´d like to have, as the result:

```
<a href='www.test.com'> Roberto C. Santos.</a>"
```

How coul´d I erase the href that is inbetween?

Comment: The thing that I was doing not right was to get the wrong element to work with. The best way that I found, up to now, to select the right element is to loop over all the elements. A nested loop would help if still not finding the exact one. For example:   

for (Element elem: contElems){
if (elem.id()!="") System.out.println(elem.id());   
    Elements contElems1=contElems.select("href, a[href], a[data-href], link[href], a[title]");
    for (Element elem1: contElems1){
        // Put code here
    }
    // (or/and) put code here
}